# apache2 Basic Proxy Pass not working

Tags: apache2, mod-proxy, proxypass

I am currently trying to set up a Vhost which links to a NodeJS App running on another port, however I can't make it work. The vhost enables without any problems and apache2 reloads/restarts without any problem. But when I want to access nodejsapp.example.com, I just get to my default page. This is my vhost file, which is mostly just copy and pasted from the official apache2 docs:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.34.567:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName nodejsapp.example.com
    ProxyPass "/" "http://example.com:3784/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://example.com:3784/"
</VirtualHost>
```

(1.2.34.567 would basically be the IP of my server, which I need to specify, as my Server has multiple IPs. This works fine with my normal vhosts)

Comment: Is mod_proxy actually enabled?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled.